# MySQL InnoDB Data_Length, Data_free and physical size of ibd file

Tags: mysql, linux, relational-database, innodb

Here is the table status of my innodb table

```
| Name | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows   | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation       | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+------+--------+---------+------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| TEST | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    | 172713 |           1175 |   203096064 |       202309632 |            0 |   5242880 |         181935 | 2015-07-21 23:52:24 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8_general_ci |     NULL |                |         |
```

Here is the physical size of the ibd file

```
213909504 Jul 22 01:35 TEST.ibd
```

So there is abount 10mb difference between the physical size of the ibd file and the Data_length of the table. I think 5.2mb is occupied by mysql as "Data_free".

My question is where does the rest of the 4.8mb data go to?

Thanks!

Erben

Answer (score 1):

`Data_free` is a tricky one to predict.

If the table was created with `innodb_file_per_table = 0`, it is the free space in `ibdata1`.  Else...

If the table is not `PARTITIONed`, and it is tiny, then it is usually zero.  I suspect it could be some small multiple of 16KB (the block size) if you have deleted a lot of stuff.

Not `PARTITIONed` and at least megabytes in size, then Data_free is usually exactly 4MB, 5MB, 6MB, or 7MB.  This is because InnoDB gets an "extent" of 8MB in anticipation of needing more space.

For `PARTITIONed` tables (before "native partitions" of 5.7.xx), each `PARTITION` looks and feels and acts like a table.  So, the `Data_free` for the *table* is really the sum of the 4-7MB for each partition.  (This is one reason for my Rule of Thumb that says "don't partition unless you expect to have at least a million rows".)

Another note:  There are various things that are "free" in InnoDB tables; the Data_free is just the tip of the iceberg.  It's not very useful.  Even with the latest stats tables, I can't get a handle on the "free" space in each secondary `INDEX`.

BTrees, when there has been a lot of deletes/inserts, settle in to about 69% full.  That 31% is not exposed in any Data_free-like metric.

**Oops**  I guess I did not answer your question.  First, the 5242880 is exactly 5*2**20 or 5MB, one of the numbers I mentioned.  I will *guess* that the other ~5MB is yet another bit of free space that is not measured cleanly.

The .ibd file, like the ibdata1 file, will never shrink.